# OCSP libraries for python / java / c?

Tags: java, python, c, ocsp

Going back to my previous question on OCSP, does anybody know of "reliable" OCSP libraries  for Python, Java and C?

I need "client" OCSP functionality, as I'll be checking the status of Certs against an OCSP responder, so responder functionality is not that important.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check pyOpenSSL.. am sure openssl supports ocsp and python binding may support it

Answer (score 3):

Java 5 has support of revocation checking via [OCSP built in](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/pki-tiger.html#OCSP). If you want to build an OCSP responder, or have finer control over revocation checking, check out [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5/overview-summary.html). You can use this to implement your own [CertPathChecker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/PKIXCertPathChecker.html) that, for example, uses non-blocking I/O in its status checks.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is the most widely used product for OCSP in C. It's quite reliable, although incredibly obtuse. I'd recommend looking at apps/ocsp.c for a pretty good example of how to make OCSP requests and validate responses.

Vista and Server 2008 have built-in OCSP support in CAPI; check out [CertVerifyRevocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377167.aspx).